# issue with deploying create-react-app using docker

Tags: reactjs, docker-compose, docker-volume

i am trying to deploy create-react-app project using docker compose with the help of volumes. I'm using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 machine. I had removed node_modules folder from the project so that I can utilize **RUN npm install** from the docker file.  But I'm getting following error logs:

> ```
> $ docker-compose up --build                                                                                             Building web
> Step 1/7 : FROM node:alpine
>  ---> ef7d474eab14
> Step 2/7 : ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 12e0998d080a
> Step 3/7 : WORKDIR '/app'
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 696072685749
> Step 4/7 : COPY package.json .
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 2de967d1753e
> Step 5/7 : RUN npm install
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> 7fff07ced071
> Step 6/7 : COPY . .
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> b0722839dcb8
> Step 7/7 : CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
>  ---> Using cache
>  ---> f5a645333123
> Successfully built f5a645333123
> Successfully tagged frontend_web:latest
> Starting frontend_web_1 ... done                                                                                        Attaching to frontend_web_1
> web_1  |
> web_1  | > frontend@0.1.0 start /app
> web_1  | > react-scripts start
> web_1  |
> web_1  | sh: react-scripts: not found
> web_1  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> web_1  | npm ERR! syscall spawn
> web_1  | npm ERR! file sh
> web_1  | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
> web_1  | npm ERR! frontend@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> web_1  | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
> web_1  | npm ERR!
> web_1  | npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.1.0 start script.
> web_1  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
> web_1  | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
> web_1  |
> web_1  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> web_1  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-02T11_14_03_294Z-debug.log
> frontend_web_1 exited with code 1
> ```

My dockerfile.dev is below:

```
FROM node:alpine

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL warn

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install 

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

And Docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version : '3'
services : 
  web:  
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes: 
      - .:/app 
      - /app/nodes_modules
```

Please let me know which step is not correct?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing last line in docker-compose.yml

```
- /app/nodes_modules
```

I think problem is because of two volumes first for parent which also take node_module as child directory and 2nd volume is creating and managed by docker itself somewhere for node_modules folder. So seems like clash between volumes for node_module folder

Answer (score 0):

I think there is typo in you docker-compose file.
- /app/node_modules not  - /app/node**s**_modules